# fatal: bad config value for 'core.sharedrepository' in ./config

Tags: git

I just entered the command:`git config core.sharedrepository 1` and I am now receiving the error:

> fatal: bad config value for 'core.sharedrepository' in ./config

Has anyone any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is exactly what it's saying: `1` is an invalid value for that setting. You probably want `true`.

From the [git-config man](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) page:

> When `group` (or `true`), the repository is made shareable between several users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are group-writable). When `all` (or `world` or `everybody`), the repository will be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable. When umask (or false), git will use permissions reported by umask(2). When `0xxx`, where `0xxx` is an octal number, files in the repository will have this mode value. `0xxx` will override user’s umask value (whereas the other options will only override requested parts of the user’s umask value). Examples: `0660` will make the repo read/write-able for the owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to group unless umask is e.g. `0022`). `0640` is a repository that is group-readable but not group-writable. See git-init(1). False by default.

Answer (score 14):

When you enter an invalid value for git config core.sharedRepository, it may fail continuously rather than let you update again with this command:

```
git core.sharedRepository group
```

In which case you will need to open up the .git/config file and alter the file manually, like so:

```
[core]
    ...
    sharedRepository = group
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `true` instead of `1` (see [Git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))

> core.sharedRepository
>
> When group (or true), the repository
>   is made shareable between several
>   users in a group (making sure all the
>   files and objects are group-writable).
>   When all (or world or everybody), the
>   repository will be readable by all
>   users, additionally to being
>   group-shareable.

Answer (score 1):

As you can check, from 1.8 onwards the boolean values for any configuration can be set as **yes/no, 1/0, true/false or on/off**. So, in the new versions the related problem is not happening anymore as you can check forward, in print example, also in the git-config manual.

1.Checking the version:

```
➜ a git:(master) git --version
git version 1.8.1.5
```

2.Checking the actual branch configuration list:

```
➜ a git:(master) git config --list --local
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
```

3.Adding a new configuration as informed:

```
➜ a git:(master) git config core.sharedrepository 1
```

4.Checking that this configuration was added:

```
➜ a git:(master) git config --list --local
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.sharedrepository=1
```

5.Adding a new configuration to show that there isn't errors:

```
➜ a git:(master) git config user.name abv
```

6.Listing all values again:

```
➜ a git:(master) git config --list --local
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.sharedrepository=1
user.name=abv
```

7.Changing core.sharedrepository to other valid boolean value:

```
➜ a git:(master) ✗ git config core.sharedrepository on
➜ a git:(master) ✗ git config --list --local
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
core.sharedrepository=on
user.name=abv
```

> The values following the equals sign in variable assign are all either
>   a string, an integer, or a boolean. Boolean values may be given as
>   yes/no, 1/0, true/false or on/off. Case is not significant in boolean
>   values, when converting value to the canonical form using --bool type
>   specifier; git config will ensure that the output is "true" or
>   "false".
>   http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/1.8.1.5

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error **go to your git project and find the folder .git** inside this folder **open with notepad or [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) *config* file.**

Then you are going to see

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    sharedRepository = true
```

change the **sharedRepository** to **true**, then you are done.