# Fatal: bad numeric config value for 'core.sharedrepository' in .git/config : invalid unit (in Git Bash)

Tags: git, config, git-bash

On performing :

```
$ git push -u origin --all
```

I got an error:

```
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
```

I googled, and find out a solution by [Richard Hansen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab).

I had to perform:

```
$ git config core.sharedRepository group
```

Rather, I executed it as:

```
$ git config core.sharedRepository dev
```

because i thought I have to enter name of group in the actual command(here "dev" is the name of the group which has a user, named "gituser").

Since then, whenever I am trying to execute any command in Git Bash, it is saying:

```
fatal: bad numeric config value 'dev' for 'core.sharedrepository' in .git/config: invalid unit
```

For this too, I found a solution at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034632/fatal-bad-config-value-for-core-sharedrepository-in-config)

which says:

> When you enter an invalid value for git config core.sharedRepository,
>   it may fail continuously rather than let you update again with this
>   command:
>
> ```
> git core.sharedRepository group
> ```
>
> In which case you will need to open up the .git/config file and alter
>   the file manually, like so:
>
> ```
> [core]
>     ...
>     sharedRepository = group
> ```

I did this, but all in vain. Still any command in Git Bash gives the same error :

```
fatal: bad numeric config value 'dev' for 'core.sharedrepository' in .git/config: invalid unit
```

Can somebody please help me in solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange, that once the value is wrong, you cannot change it anymore... What I also encountered: trying to `git config core.sharedRepository group` as root caused the same error message. For the command it was necessary to login as the owner of the config file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I thought I have to enter name of group in the actual command

No: `dev` is simply not a valid value for that setting.

Try '`group`' only.

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

If you need to modify manually the config, make sure to look for the `.git/config` file in your *local* cloned repo (not on the server).

The correct values are:

core.sharedRepository

> - **`group`** (or `true`):  the repository is made shareable between several users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are group-writable).
> - **`all`** (or `world` or `everybody`): the repository will be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable.
> - **`umask`** (or `false`): Git will use permissions reported by `umask(2)`.
> - **`0xxx`**: where `0xxx` is an octal number, files in the repository will have this mode value. `0xxx` will override user’s umask value (whereas the other options will only override requested parts of the user’s umask value).

Examples:

> - `0660` will make the repo read/write-able for the owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to `group` unless umask is e.g. `0022`).
> - `0640` is a repository that is group-readable but not group-writable.

Comment: Yes Von, I am trying the command with 'group', but the output is always 'fatal: bad numeric config value.......'. Infact executing even 'git status' is giving the same fatal error. I dont know how to revert back '$ git config core.sharedRepository dev'.

Comment: @AshishGoyal you should be able to modify the `.git/config` file manually.

Comment: I am trying:
$ git config core.sharedRepository group

Comment: @AshishGoyal can you try and modify the `.git/config` file manually?

Comment: I tried that too, went to .git/config, under [core], i included 'shareRepository = group'. After saving the changes, when I come back to GitBash, still the same fatal error issue persists.

Comment: @AshishGoyal you should not have included `shareRepository`: that setting should already have been there. If it was not, that means you are modifying the wrong config file. Check also your global config file just in case: `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: @AshishGoyal make sure to modify the right local config file, the one at the root folder of your current repo, in `.git` subfolder.

Comment: ~/.gitconfig contains only two things '[http]' and '[https]' with respective proxy addresses. The path where .gitconfig is present, same path includes .git directory, inside which there is a config file. I included 'sharedRepository = group' in it. Apart from this my directory 'project.git' (which I clone in my local machine), it also has a config file, it also did not have sharedRepository parameter inside it. I included in that and tested. But it too doesnt solve the problem.

Comment: @AshishGoyal wrong path. Go to the root folder of your repo: there will be a `.git` in it, with a `config` file: modify that file.

Comment: @AshishGoyal If you have to add sharedRepository, you are in the wrong file.

Comment: Whoa! Thank you so much Von! Finally I found the correct config file. I was searching for the config file in the git server. Instead I found it in my local machine, inside the folder which contained code files. Now all git commands are working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @AshishGoyal I have edited the answer to make clear where to look.