# Have multiple Git users push the same local repo reflect on their own account

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have a pc that currently has git configured for myself including ssh keys. I have another person that will need to use my pc to work on the same project as me. Is there a way to configure my local repo so that we can switch between the users such that the author is correctly reflected on our Gitlab accounts too?

I know that we can change the configs to reflect our username and emails, but this only affects the commit. If they push, it lists me as the author instead of them despite the commit doing it correctly. I'm also aware the simpler option would be to make another clone of the repo and create a local config and ssh for the two, but that won't be feasible in this case as there's not enough storage to clone another copy (pc has ~100GB of disk space and the repo is ~60GB).

Comment: My advice is to explore this route: 2 different accounts in the OS (with different global `.gitconfig`s) and one [group-shareable local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034671/7976758).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193032/7976758

Comment: @phd Thanks, I tried this just now and it was able to resolve the issue